# I can't seem to find the issue in this printing program

Tags: java

I'm learning Java on one of the free websites out there and I can't get over the issue here, the program wants me to print a right sided triangle.

```
public class PrintingLikeBoss {

// copy or rewrite the method of Assignment 39.1 here
public static void printStars(int amount) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void printWhitespaces(int amount) {
    // 40.1
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}

public static void printTriangle(int size) {
    // 40.2
    int j = size;
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        printWhitespaces(j);
        printStars(i);
        j -= 1;
    }
}

public static void xmasTree(int height) {
    // 40.3
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Tests do not use main, yo can write code here freely!

    printTriangle(5);
    System.out.println("---");
    xmasTree(4);
    System.out.println("---");
    xmasTree(10);
}
```

}

The output I get seems good

```
compile:
run:

    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
---
---
```

*The error I get is "Do not put a extra whitespace at the start of the line in printTriangle"*

This is a specific error that is related to the lesson, the program runs with no problem.

Comment: You start your loop with `0`, so it will print 0 stars in the first iteration ... what do you think is the meaning of this?

Comment: Hint: replace spaces with dashes to see what's going on ([demo](http://ideone.com/0HOOjn)).

Comment: Thanks, the dashes really helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you check the actual values passed to your methods, you will find that your method `printTriangle()` first calls

```
 printWhitespaces(5);
```

and then

```
 printStarts(0);
```

So; you first print 5 whitespaces; then **zero** stars; then a newline.

Thus the problem is: for the first iteration of your loop, you are not printing *any* stars; just spaces+newline. In other words: your triangle starts with an *empty* line.

Maybe that is what the assignment checker complains about. So you could try to change your loop in `printTriangle()` to start with 1; not 0. Because then you will print at least one * on that first line.

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't want the whitespace in the fist line just do that

```
  public static void printTriangle(int size) {
    // 40.2
    int j = size;
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        printWhitespaces(j);
        printStars(i);
        j -= 1;
    }
}
```

just change i from 0 to 1 
I hope i help you